# Displaying a table with two columns in Fortran with available data

Tags: fortran

I have two variables say `x` and `y` and both have around 60 points in them(basically values of the `x` and `y` axis of the plot). Now when I try to display it in the result file in form of a column or a  table with the `x` value and the corresponding `y` value I end up with all the `x` values displayed in both the columns followed then by the `y` values. I am unable to get it out correctly.

This is a small part of the code

```
xpts = PIC1(1,6:NYPIX,1)
ypts = PIC1(2,6:NYPIX,1)
write(21,*), NYPIX
write(21,"(T2,F10.4: T60,F10.4)"), xpts, ypts
```

This is the output I get. the `x` values continue from the column `1` to `2` till all are displayed and then the `y` values are displayed.

```
   128.7018                                                  128.7042
   128.7066                                                  128.7089
   128.7113                                                  128.7137
   128.7160                                                  128.7184
   128.7207                                                  128.7231
   128.7255                                                  128.7278
   128.7302                                                  128.7325
   128.7349                                                  128.7373
   128.7396                                                  128.7420
   128.7444                                                  128.7467
   128.7491                                                  128.7514
   128.7538                                                  128.7562
   128.7585                                                  128.7609
   128.7633                                                  128.7656
   128.7680                                                  128.7703
   128.7727                                                  128.7751
   128.7774                                                  128.7798
   128.7822                                                  128.7845
   128.7869                                                  128.7892
   128.7916                                                  128.7940
   128.7963                                                  128.7987
   128.8011                                                  128.8034
    86.7117                                                   86.7036
    86.6760                                                   86.6946
    86.6317                                                   86.6467
    86.6784                                                   86.8192
    86.8634                                                   87.0909
    87.2584                                                   87.6427
    88.1245                                                   88.8343
    89.5275                                                   90.2652
    91.0958                                                   91.8668
    92.6358                                                   93.2986
    93.8727                                                   94.4631
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `do` loop:

```
do i=1,size(xpts)
  write(21,"(T2,F10.4: T60,F10.4)"), xpts(i), ypts(i)
enddo
```

Comment: Thank you . That was indeed helpful.

Comment: sorry i am sort of new to this site so i wasn't sure of what I was doing. But no your answer was really helpful and I got the output up and running using this.Cheers

Comment: What does the `:` do after `F10.4`?

Answer (score 1):

There is already [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692079) saying how to get the output as wanted.  It may be good, though, to explicitly say why the (unwanted) output as in the question comes about.

In the (generalized) statement

```
write(unit,fmt) xpts, ypts
```

the `xpts, ypts` is the output list.  In the description of how the output list is treated we see (Fortran 2008 9.6.3)

> If an array appears as an input/output list item, it is treated as if the elements, if any, were specified in array element order

That is, it shouldn't be too surprising that (assuming the lower bound of `xpts` and `ypts` are `1`)

```
write(unit, fmt) xpts(1), xpts(2), xpts(3), ..., ypts(1), ypts(2), ...
```

gives the output seen.

Using a do loop expanded as

```
write(unit, fmt) xpts(1), ypts(1)
write(unit, fmt) xpts(2), ypts(2)
...
```

is indeed precisely what is wanted here.  However, a more general "give me the elements of the arrays interleaved" could be done with an output implied-do:

```
write(unit, fmt) (xpts(i), ypts(i), i=LBOUND(xpts,1),UBOUND(xpts,1))
```

(assuming that the upper and lower bounds of `ypts` are the same as `xpts`).

This is equivalent to

```
write(unit, fmt) xpts(1), ypts(1), xpts(2), ypts(2), ...
```

(again, for convenience switching to the assumption about lower bounds).

This implied-do may be more natural in some cases.  In particular note that the first explicit do loop writes one record for each pair of elements from `xpts` and `ypts`; for the implied-do the new record comes about from format reversion.  The two for the format in the question are equivalent, but for some more exotic formats the former may not be what is wanted and it ties the structure of the do loop to the format.

This splitting of records holds even more so for unformatted output (which hasn't format reversion).