# Printing arrayed variables in a file in a specific format in Fortran

Tags: arrays, formatting, fortran

I have two arrays. The first one is A(3,3,100). This means that for each n from 1 to 100, I have a 3x3 matrix given by Aij. The second array, B(100), is a one-dimensional array in which i have values at each n.

Now, I want to print A and B in a file such that the arrangement would be:

A11,1   A21,1  A31,1  A12,1  A22,1  A32,1  A13,1  A23,1  A33,1  B,1

A11,2  A21,2  A31,2  A12,2  A22,2  A32,2  A13,2  A23,2  A33,2  B,2

**.**          **.**           **.**           **.**           **.**          **.**           **.**          **.**          **.**         **.**

**.**          **.**           **.**           **.**           **.**          **.**           **.**          **.**          **.**         **.**

**.**          **.**           **.**           **.**           **.**          **.**           **.**          **.**          **.**         **.**

A11,n  A21,n  A31,n  A12,n  A22,n  A32,n  A13,n  A23,n  A33,n   B,n

I tried doing this by using: `write(*,'(9Fw.d 1Fw.d)') A,B` where `w` is the field width and `d` is allotted for the decimals; but it doesn't work.

Comment: As I imagine you haven't a problem with the format itself, but the order in which the elements of the array are written, you should be able to build on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28691924/3157076).

Comment: Welcome, please take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask]. Please *never* say *"it doesn't work"*. Really never. Instead tell us what happened. Was the output wrong? How did it look like? Was there any error message? Copy the output here and show the details.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement will first print out all of A, then it will print out all of B. Just break it up with a do loop and implied do loops in the write statement:

```
do i = 1, n
   write(*,'(9Fw.d, 1Fw.d)') ((A(row, col,i), row=1,3),col=1,3), B(i)
end do
```

Are you sure this is the order you want? A11,1 A21,1 A31,1 ...... This would be going down rows. I would think you would want each row printed together like this: A11,1 A12,1 A13,1 A21,1 ..... If that is the case, swap the row=1,3),col=1,3)

Comment: thank you very much! it worked perfectly! yes! but thank you also for the additional information :)

Comment: @user2889824 Please take the [tour] I linked already. You will find out how to accept a correct answer.